# iText 7 html to pdf conversion only outputs the first page

Tags: c#, itext7

I am using itext 7's pdfHTML to convert my html into pdf. It works fine, however, it only saves a pdf of 1 page. The rest of my html content is ignored. I haven't found anything related to this particular problem anywhere. Any ideas?

Here is the code I use:

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(fullHtmlString, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));
```

I've double checked my html string and it's valid html. One thing to note is that I have a `<table>` with dozens of `<tr>`s. Is that a problem?

UPDATE: When I remove `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` from my html string it prints fine on multiple pages, but I am losing my included css files in the `<head>` ..

Comment: Thanks @KJ . I ended up removing the tags I mentioned above and applying inline styles for my elements. Strange, but this is the only way I could get it to work ..

Comment: Hi, can you attach your minimal HTML file that reproduces the problem?

Comment: My HTML file starts with a `DIV` tag and inside that I have multiple Google charts. I'm facing same issue where only first page is getting rendered and not the rest.